# Swift - Title Not Appearing for Navigation View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I have a navigation view controller that upon action sends a segue to a tab bar view controller. Because of this segue the tabbed view controller inherits the navigation bar. I am trying to apply a title to one of my view controllers attached to the tab bar view controller, but setting the title via code is not working for me. does anyone know the reason why that could be?

Here is a picture of my storyboard:

[image: storuboard]

The view controller with the logout button is where I am trying to set the title in the nav bar (code):

```
import UIKit

class ProfileSettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        self.navigationItem.title = "Profile Settings"

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil


    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func logoutButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        PFUser.logOut()
        var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("userLoggedOut", sender: self)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)

    }

}
```

View controller embedded in the navigation controller triggering the segue to the tab bar controller:

```
import UIKit

class UserRegistrationViewController: UIViewController {


    func displayAlert(title:String, error:String) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {
            action in



        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    @IBOutlet var usernameTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func registerUser(sender: AnyObject) {

        var error = ""

        if usernameTextField.text == nil || emailTextField.text == nil || passwordTextField.text == nil {

            error = "Please enter a username, email and password"

        }


        if error != "" {

            displayAlert("Error In Form", error: error)

        } else {

            var user = PFUser.currentUser()

            user.username = usernameTextField.text
            user.password = passwordTextField.text
            user.email = emailTextField.text

            user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (succeeded: Bool!, signupError: NSError!) -> Void in
                if signupError == nil {

                    println(user.username)
                    println(user.password)
                    println(user.email)


                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("successfulRegistration", sender: self)

                    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)

                    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                } else {

                    if let errorString = signupError.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString {
                        error = errorString
                    } else {

                        error = "Please try again later."

                    }


                    self.displayAlert("Could Not Sign Up", error: error)

                }
            }


        }


    }



}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This worked for me: `self.parent?.title = "nav bar title"`

Answer (score 21):

In your view controller hierarchy, navigation bar is displaying the title of `UITabBarController`, not view controllers inside the `UITabBarController`.

Easiest way to get title shown in navigation bar would be

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Profile Settings"

}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be fixing the issue. My navigation bar is not actually appearing. Could it be due to the fact that I'm calling `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil` in my `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Sorry disregard the last comment. I had set the navigationController to false. Say I had a non-navigation controller segue to the tabbed bar controller. Would I set this command on the segue action from non-navigation controller?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Profile Settings"
```

Answer (score 7):

**SWIFT 3**

If embedded in a UINavigationController, you can set the title as follows from within your ViewController's viewDidLoad() method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    /* If view controller is a direct child of UINavigationController */
    self.title = "Title Here"

    /* If view controller's parent is a direct child of UINavigationController e.g. a child of embedded tab view controller */
    self.parent?.title = "Title Here" 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In the Logout Screen viewcontroller add this -

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title="Profile Settings"
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5 Simple answer please follow that

```
self.title = "Your Title"

or 

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.title = "Your Title"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check commented lines for usability ViewController with and without Tabbarcontroller

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    addNavBarImage()
}

func addNavBarImage() {

    let navController = self.navigationController!
    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "navview") //Your logo url here
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    let bannerWidth = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
    let bannerHeight = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
    let bannerX = bannerWidth / 2 - (image.size.width) / 2
    let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - (image.size.height) / 2
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit


    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView //  ViewController without Tabbarcontroller 

    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.titleView = imageView //ViewController with Tabbarcontroller 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into your viewcontroller:

```
// title color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
```

It's working for me. I hope this help for someone.