# Navigation Bar Title Not Showing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I configure my navigationBar like this in the AppDelegate:

```
func setupNavBar() {
    let barAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    barAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: appRed]
    barAppearance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: .white), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    barAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

This works fine, however when I set the title as follows:

```
navigationController.navigationItem.title = "Hello"
```

this never works and I do not see any title. This is regardless of where I place the above line (viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear etc.)

Comment: Does it show without setting up the appearance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25167491/8272698 check this out, maybe this will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the view controller's title property to "Hello"

```
self.title = "Hello"
```

If it works, you can find an explanation in AWebster's answer here [Swift - Title Not Appearing for Navigation View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676757/swift-title-not-appearing-for-navigation-view-controller)